# CDH 5.4 upgrade to HUE to 3.8

Tags: upgrade, cloudera-cdh, hue

I am using `CDH 5.4`. I see the version of `HUE` is `3.7`.

I want to use `Spark notebook` feature in `HUE 3.8` but I do not know how to upgrade `HUE` to `3.8`

Comment: Notebooks are in beta and not supported in CDH yet. The recommended way to try them is the developer way for now: http://gethue.com/new-notebook-application-for-spark-sql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the instruction how to update `HUE` at [HUE wiki page](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/wiki/Howto:-Upgrade-HUE). It is removed now so I place my update bash script here

```
#!/bin/bash

CDH_LIB=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib

# Download tarball
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/730827/hue/releases/3.8.1/hue-3.8.1.tgz

# Backup old version
sudo mv $CDH_LIB/hue $CDH_LIB/hue-3.7

# Install libs
sudo apt-get -y install python2.7-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libxslt1-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get -y install make
sudo apt-get -y install libkrb5-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libldap2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install python-pip
sudo apt-get -y install libsasl2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install python-ldap

tar -zxvf hue-3.8.1.tgz
cd hue-3.8.1/

#sudo rm -rf /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hue
# Build
sudo PREFIX=$CDH_LIB make install

# Copy configs
sudo rsync -aL $CDH_LIB/hue-3.7/desktop/conf/ $CDH_LIB/hue/desktop/conf/

# Copy db
sudo cp $CDH_LIB/hue-3.7/desktop/desktop.db $CDH_LIB/hue/desktop/desktop.db

# Sync db
sudo $CDH_LIB/hue/build/env/bin/hue syncdb
sudo $CDH_LIB/hue migate
```